# How to rewrite url in htaccess file in php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to php.
My .htaccess file is below

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

With this the following url formats are working fine

- `/?qa=123/why-do-birds-sing`
- `/?qa=123&qa_1=why-do-birds-sing`
- `/index.php?qa=123&qa_1=why-do-birds-sing`

But i want to make in to the below format

```
site.com/123/why-do-birds-sing
```

I tried adding the below line

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

But the `site.com/123/why-do-birds-sing` is not working. What changes should i make to get the desired url format working?

P.S `site.com/index.php/123/why-do-birds-sing` is working, but i want to rewrite  without index.php

Comment: `site.com/123/why-do-birds-sing` works for me using above rule. What error are you getting?

Comment: 'm getting 404 error. 
It works fine when i goto `site.com/index.php/123/why-do-birds-sing`

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 1):

The way rewrite rules work is they take whatever is/are in the parameter(s) and reconstructs the url to a more readable and user friendly url. While at the same time passing the parameters (secretly) to your page for use.

You can then access the parameters on the receiving page normally with `$_GET['my-parameter']`

Below is the rewrite rule you need.

In this part `^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$` it writes everything before the slash as your first parameter and everything after the slash as your second parameter. Allowing for any mixture of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers 0-9, underscores & hyphens.

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$    index.php?qa=$1&qa_1=$2    [NC,L]
```

Then construct your links like this... `123/why-do-birds-sing`

Your url will look like `http://example.com/123/why-do-birds-sing`

Comment: Thanks @kuya
in the first line I have `DirectoryIndex index.php`, so this means that it will only rewrite when url has index.php in it?

Comment: The line `DirectoryIndex index.php` has nothing to do with rewrites. That line is used **only if** you want to use something **other than** `index.php` as your index page on the site. For example (since linux is case sensitive) you might want to use Index.php as your index page throughout the site. In which case you can use `DirectoryIndex` to make the change. If you're going to use `index.php` as your index page, the line `DirectoryIndex index.php` can be deleted. It doesn't change anything since `index.php` is already default index page.